# Hide/show long text in a table cell HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a HTML table, which is populated from a MySQL database by php. I'm using css provided by Bootstrap. Anyway my problem is that in some of the columns I have a long text contained in each cell. I'm using a css which hide the content showing just a part of it because I want to keep my table as compact as possible. I tried a solution with jquery but I'm not really good with it and it doesn't work. I know that there are other discussion about this but I haven't benn able to make those work.

```
<tbody aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
 <?php
 $i=0;
 while ($i < $num) {
   $process=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"process");
   $A=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"A");
   $B=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"B");
   $time_A=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"time_A");
   $time_B=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"time_B");
   ?>

   <tr class="odd">
     <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $process;?></font></td>
     <td ><div id="text"><a class="toggle"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $A;?></font></a></div></td>
     <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $B;?></font></td>
     <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $time_A;?></font></td>
     <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $time_B;?></font></td>
   </tr>
   <?php 
   $i++; 
 } 
 ?>
</tbody>
```

Here' the script:

```
<script>

    $('.toggle').click(function(){ 
        var target = $(this).closest('#text');
        if (target.hasClass('expanded')) {
            target.removeClass('expanded');
            $(this).text('(expand)');
        } else {
            target.addClass('expanded');
            $(this).text('(collapse)');
        }
    });

    </script>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#text { 
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:300px;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
#text.expanded {
    max-height:none;
}
```

Comment: Set actual complete value in td title property and it'll be shown on mouse over.

Comment: You are using id="text" in a loop, this will result in a lot of elements with the same id. This will probably break your jQuery call, use class instead

Comment: what is with the <font> tags??? Please use css instead!

Comment: Michiel you're right. I corrected it, now i'm using css. By the way your solution seems not working. malkam i haven't really understood what you mean. I did what you sad but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering OP's comment about requirement to copy/paste the contents of the cell, put it in the data-content attribute of a Boostrap popover and that should solve the problem:

HTML:

```
<td>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-link too-long" title="Optional Title" 
  data-content='Content that is too long to display because there is too much of it to fit in your table cell. But it all fits in this popover!' 
  data-placement="bottom">
  Content that is too long to display...</a>
</td>
```

JS:

```
$('#too-long').popover()
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MjsAp/3/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

Change `id="test"` in your html to `class="text"`

and change your qQuery:

```
    var target = $(this).closest('#text');
```

to

```
    var target = $(this).closest('.text');
```

jQuery doesn't know which #text you're refering to because #text should be unique.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? I don't think it so obvious what you realyl want to achieve.

Comment: Since i'm using a css which hide (with overflow:hidden) my text, i want that when i click on the text in the cell it shows me all the text contained in the cell. For example you can think about phpmyadmin which makes what i sad. May be i made a big mistake trying my solution, because what i'm trying to explain looks more like a popup.

Answer (score 0):

You could duplicate the contents of the cell into the title property. User sees contents as tooltip when they mouse over.

```
<td>
  <div id="test" title="Cell contents that are very long ...">
    Cell contents that are very long...
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Ok. But i need to select that text to copy it when i need it. With your solution i can't do that.

Comment: Ah yes, that's trickier. Maybe a popover: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: Why not just put in a data-attribute value as well (along with title attribute)